# How do I create the effect used in the "Scribd" logo?

Tags: logo

I would like to know how to create this effect which is on this logo:

[image]

I am talking about changing smooth color of the Scribd blue dot. Thanks!

Comment: Check out the answers on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3465/how-to-create-these-two-buttons

Comment: Most of this look can be created by 3 color gradient: Light blue - Dark blue - Light blue. For things like this you want to turn to the good ol' blending options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a basic thing to do in Photoshop. In regards to everybody saying that these types are gradients: Yes it looks like a gradient, but if you look closely you can see the gradient type is rounded. Now of course we can say "this is a radial gradient then". Sure we can!

A way simpler solution is to turn on bevel and emboss and simply soften it out.

Result:

[image: logo recreation]

Comment: You butchered that logo.. And I stand behind my words that _most of that look_ can be created by 3 color gradient.

Comment: Heres example http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/181/scribd.jpg - Last 2 logo circles are recreations.

Comment: I did not say it couldnt be done, don't be offended. The easy way for him to accomplish this is to simply use a bevel. And its not about the logo, its about the dot. But eh, thanks for the -1 i guess

Comment: I'm not offended, I'm just stunned how you made that circle that doesn't look anything like the original and all this while saying that its not a gradient. When actually a 3 color gradient does almost perfect job. Its not like setting 3 colors in a gradient is somehow difficult. The minus point was given because you butchered that blue circle. Its not even the same color.

Comment: Its not about the actual circle, it is about the technique behind it. This took me just a few seconds, but it got the job done to explain the technique. I can make it 1 on 1, but why should i? I do not think he will use the actual circrle shape... otherwise the advice would be: take your eliptical marque tool and select the cirle, then press CTRL + C. But eh, you are entitled to your opinion, so it is all good

Comment: Well, yea. I don't understand how it can be the technique behind the original one when it doesn't look but remotely like the original one? ( Remotely looks like meaning that its blue and has a circle shape. )

Comment: I don't think the source image can be properly analyzed if it's that small.

Comment: I know this is nearly two years ago, but I would say it's more appropriate to make your own answer, Joonas, rather than berate the only person who bothered answering this question.