# How can I use CSS to make something look "pushed"?

Tags: css, dreamweaver

I'm building a new website in Dreamweaver CS5 and I've made a default spry menu bar. Now I want that the menu bar has an 3D look. When you click the button on the menu bar, I would like an effect that makes the button look pushed. How can I accomplish that?

Here is my design so far:

[image: screenshot of dreamweaver]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Making something look raised or "pushed' is all about lighting and shadows. The human eye and brain interprets shadows as depth. So if you adjust shadows, you can give off the perceptions of depth in a specific area.

For a button, adding a shadow below the element in the resting state causes the element to appear raised. If you move the shadow to the top of the element, the element appears sunken or pushed.

You can do this with CSS.

Basically style the link/button to have a box shadow. A gradient fill helps a little bit as will a slight text shadow on any text.

[image: rest state]

The key elements for the above are the background:

```
background: #a00;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a90329 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a90329 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%);
```

The Text shadow:

```
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #301;
```

And the box shadow:

```
-webkit-box-shadow:  0px 2px 5px 1px rgba(155, 155, 155, .5);
box-shadow:  0px 2px 5px 1px rgba(155, 155, 155, .5);
```

These three items give the perception of a raised item.

To make the object appear sunken or pushed.....

[image: pushed]

I reverse the background gradient:

```
background: #a00;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6d0019), color-stop(56%,#8f0222), color-stop(100%,#a90329));
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6d0019 0%,#8f0222 56%,#a90329 100%);
```

Removed the text shadow:

```
text-shadow: none;
```

Moved the box shadow to an inset shadow on the top of the element:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
```

To further aid the illusion, I also changed the text color from white in the resting state to a light grey in the active state.

These are all basic CSS3 items. If you need support for older browsers such as IE7, you may be better off utilizing images rather than CSS. However, if using images the light and shadow principals I've described here still apply if you want to create a sense of depth.

**[A working demo can be found HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/GkwUm/4/)** but has only been tested in Google Chrome. ***You may need to refine and adjust code to support browsers other than Chrome.***

Comment: Great answer Scott. Implied dimension is all about light. Just keep in mind that dimensionality has been done with a heavy hand all over the web in years past. The trend now is to move away from such gross application of "affordance" and move toward more careful use of gradients, borders, and inset and outset box shadows. The more ostentatious you are with your effects, the more out of date your design will seem.

Comment: True. :) I was covering implementation, not aesthetics specifically :)

Comment: I almost forgot about this fun little utility: [The Button Builder](http://livetools.uiparade.com/button-builder.html) from UI Parade.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your asnwer, I founded out how it works. It looks Awesome!! This site was also helpful for me: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/